# postdrop : create file maildrop/xxxxxx.xxxxx : Permission Denied

Tags: apache2

[image]I'm getting this error on the Apache2 server and after some time server is going down (Page simple isn't loading).
I got more than 2k errors in ~5h.

! Maybe it's not the reason why the webpage is going down but anyway I have to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey there, have you found a solution? Having same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem using this source: [LinuxHostingSupport.net](http://linuxhostingsupport.net/blog/postdrop-mail_queue_enter-create-file-maildrop-permission-denied)

If shorten:

**1**. Check the ownership/permissions of the postfix files:

> **sudo /etc/init.d/postfix check**

**2**. Got 3 outlines:

> *postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by postfix: /var/spool/postfix/public*

> *postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by postfix: /var/spool/postfix/maildrop*

***This can be skiped, it's just a simple warning***

> *postfix/postfix-script: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out*

**3**. Stop the postfix service:

> **sudo killall -9 postdrop**

**4**. Correct the ownership of the above directories:

> **sudo chown postfix.postdrop /var/spool/postfix/public -R**

> **sudo chown postfix.postdrop /var/spool/postfix/maildrop -R**

**5**. Now, start the postfix service:

> **sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start**

*Emails should now be working fine.*